# Inequalities with min and max

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $n$ sets $a_i$, $i\in[1, n]$. Is it true to say

$$\min\sum_{i=1}^na_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^n\min a_i \quad\text{and}\quad\max\sum_{i=1}^na_i \le \sum_{i=1}^n\max a_i $$

Comment: Yes because $min$ [or $max$] conditions for each $A_i$ can be different. The equality can happen only when $min$ [or $max$] conditions happen at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$min(A_i)\leq A_i \leq max(A_i)\quad (i=1,2,\dots,n)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^nmin(A_i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n A_i \leq\sum_{i=1}^n max(A_i)$$
$$\therefore \sum_{i=1}^nmin(A_i)\leq min\left(\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\right)\quad,\quad max\left(\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n max(A_i)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{i=1}^n A_i = \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i | a_i \in A_i, \forall i\}$.

Let $\alpha_i = \min_{a \in A_i} a$. One of the n-tuples considered in $\sum_{i=1}^n A_i$ is $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n)$, therefore, $\min \left( \sum_{i=1}^n A_i \right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \min_{a \in A_i} a$. Similarly for $\max$.